# Spock interaction based test does not fail

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following two Spock tests:

```
def "sends a valid response when no users exist"() {
    setup:
    def exchange = new HttpServerExchange(Mock(ServerConnection))
    usersRepository.size() >> 0

    when:
    firstRunHandler.handleRequest(exchange)

    then:
    1*response.send(exchange, _)
}

def "does not send content when any users exist"() {
    setup:
    usersRepository.size() >> 1

    when:
    firstRunHandler.handleRequest(new HttpServerExchange(Mock(ServerConnection)))

    then:
    0*response.send(_, _)
}
```

The second one should definitely fail, since the interaction is stll there. But it always passes. I can not even make it fail with:

```
then:
assert false
0*response.send(_, _)
```

IntelliJ Idea still shows it as "green". But when I change the "then" to

```
then:
assert false
```

the test fails, so it is definitely being run and executed as a spock test.

I don't get much info from Spock, and I did not find out anything when debugging. What am I missing? What can I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: If `assert false` doesn't make the test fail, then something fundamental is wrong, such as the test not being run, or not being run as a Spock test.

Comment: The test is being run, as a spock test. IntelliJ Idea shows the Test as green. When I remove the "0*response.sen(_, _)", the "assert false" makes the test fail.

Comment: Strange. To help further, I'd need a way to reproduce this.

Comment: I could send you the project if you want. It's just a toy project anyway - so far... And its not that big. Ping by email (david@davidtanzer.net) or @dtanzer on twitter, and I'll send you the sources later today.

Comment: What is 'response' in these tests? I don't see it defined anywhere. Is it something that is mocked? If you write a test with `expect: 1 * response._` does the test pass or fail?

Comment: Response is a mock that is defined in the "setup" method of the test.